# Structural equivalence between functions ( does this concept have a name? )

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm searching for the name of a category of similarity between functions; which takes the following form:

Suppose for some pair of surjective functions
$f: X\rightarrow Y \subseteq X$,
$g: A \rightarrow B \subseteq A$.

Suppose also that $h: X\rightarrow A$ and $i: Y\rightarrow B$ are bijective and total.

The following must hold true:

$f(x)=y \iff g(h(x)) = i(y)$ 
and conversely
$g(a)=b \iff f(h^{-1}(a)) = i^{-1}(b)$

Is there a name for a more arbitrary type of equivalence which holds over functions with arbitrary sets as their domain?

Comment: I do not see the connection between $f$ and $g$. What do you mean by "form a closure over their domains"?

Comment: I saved the question before I thought it fully through, it's been updated just now so hopefully the meaning is clearer. By "form a closure" I mean the range of the function is a subset of its domain.

Comment: Is your property, something along these lines, let be $\varphi : X \to A$ and $\psi : Y \to B$ two bijections: $\forall y \in Y, b = \psi(y) \implies f^{-1}(\{ y \}) = \{ x \} \text{ and } g^{-1}(\{ b \}) = \{ a \} \text{ and } \varphi(x) = b$ ?

Comment: So, do you mean the following? You call $f:X\rightarrow Y\subseteq X$ equivalent to $g: A\rightarrow B\subseteq A$ iff there exists a bijection $h: X\rightarrow A$ such that $$ g\circ h = h\circ f?$$

Comment: Severin that seems correct to me, yes.

Comment: We say that $f$ and $g$ are conjugated. There are several stronger versions of this, e.g. we call $f$ and $g$ topologically conjugated if $h$ is a homeomorphism. These kind of things are for example studied in dynamical systems. Check this one https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_conjugacy

Comment: Thank you Severin :)
Raito - I'm not sure whether my idea corresponds with your formulae but just out of interest what was the concept you had in mind?

Comment: Update: after reading over the comments again I've decided that conjugation is not what I was thinking of. Raito your formulation is correct. The question has been updated.